# How to autoplay a YouTube video in a UIWebView swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, youtube, uiwebview

I'm having an issue trying to autoplay my UIWebView.

here's my code:

```
WebVideo.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
WebVideo.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false

WebVideo.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(WebVideo.frame.width)\" height=\"\(WebVideo.frame.height)\" src=\"\(thumbnail)?playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen & autoplay=1 &showinfo=0 &controls=0 autohide=1></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
```

now This does not work. and I tried with this code too:

```
 WebVideo.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
 WebVideo.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false

 WebVideo.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(WebVideo.frame.width)\" height=\"\(WebVideo.frame.height)\" src=\"\(thumbnail)&autoplay=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
```

It does not work either

Can you help me, how do I autoplay..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced similar issue and ended up using helper Library of Google

https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

```
    let player = YTPlayerView(frame: CGRect(0,0,view.frame.width , 300))
    let dict = ["modestbranding" : 0,"controls" : 1 ,"autoplay" : 1,"playsinline" : 1,"autohide" : 1,"showinfo" : 0]
    player.loadWithVideoId("video-ID" ,playerVars: dict)
    player.delegate = self
```

Call this delegate function then

```
func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: YTPlayerView) {
    playerView.playVideo()

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was perfect

Answer (score 0):

`allowsInlineMediaPlayback` worked for me. However, in the meanwhile Apple recommends using `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`: `Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.` Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview